# How to compare ids of different formats across databases

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

**Problem**: I need a way to compare ids of a type `varchar` to ids of a type `int`.

**Background**: I have a list of ids that *almost* map to the ids in my table.  I have ~10k ids, but I suspect there are only 3-5 variations to clean up.

The tables I'm working with could be simplified as follows.  A big table of articles with good ids, and a temp table I've dumped all the dirty ids into.  I'd like to update my temp table with the correct id whenever I'm able to make a match

```
licensing.articles
+----------+
| id (int) |
+----------+
| 1000     |
| 1001     |
| 1002     |
+----------+

tempDB.ids
+-------------------+----------------+
| id_dirty (string) | id_clean (int) |
+-------------------+----------------+
| 1000Z             |                |
| R1001             |                |
| 1002              |                |
+-------------------+----------------+
```

So my first query is the simple version: for records that share the same id between the `licensing.articles` table and the `tempDB.ids` table, I want to populate `tempDB.ids.id_clean` with the good id.  (In my example, there is one shared id (1002), but in reality there's probably ~3k of them.)

When I try something like this:

```
UPDATE tempDB.ids AS dirty
JOIN licensing.articles clean ON clean.id = CAST(dirty.id_dirty as unsigned)
SET dirty.id_clean = clean.id
WHERE isnull(dirty.id_clean);
```

I get an error message `Error : Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '1000Z'`.  That makes sense; presumably it is failing to convert '1000Z' to an integer.

So how can I say

- FOR ONLY `tempDB.ids.id_dirty` values that can be successfully cast to an int
- SELECT the matching record from `licensing.articles`
- AND copy `licensing.articles.id` to `tempDB.ids.id_clean`

Comment: If this is one time, could you just join on `tempdb.id_Dirty like concatt('%',articles.ID,'%')` you may however get a few false positives....  casting int should be done implicitly this way.

Comment: Use `WHERE Column REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'` to determine values that can be cast to int